# Ajax uploads not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm having some trouble figuring out whats wrong with my ajax request.
Its a script for uploading pictures.

The php file sets up a page with an inline popup for selecting images and displaying their previews

the selection is done in a form called #uploads and if the form is submitted it works the way its supposed to, refreshing to a page where the $_FILES info is included

the php file:

```
<?php
echo (print_r($_FILES));
$html = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/style.css">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="bilder"></div>
    <div id="nybild">
        <div id="ny_header">
        <form id="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="filer" name="filer" multiple>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <div id="preview"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="add">Lägg till</button>
            <button id="cancel">Avbryt</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="lagg_till">Lägg till nu bild</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/page.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
';
echo $html;
```

The java script file contains the logic for showing selection popup, creating previews of files and finally uploading them with ajax. This last part however does not work. The page returned displays an empty $_FILES array

page.js:

```
$(function(){
    $nybild =   $("#nybild");
    $overlay = $("#overlay");
    $overlay2 = $("#overlay2");
    $preview = $("#preview");

$("#lagg_till").click(function(){
    $overlay.show();
    $nybild.show();
});

$("#filer").on("change", function(){
    $preview.html("");
    var files = this.files;
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        if(files[i].type.match("image.*")){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(theFile){
                return function(e){
                    $preview.append(["<img src='", e.target.result, "' class='thumb' title='", escape(theFile.name), "'/>"].join(''));
                };
            })(files[i]);
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        }
    }
});

$("#cancel").click(close_nybild);

$("#add").click(function(){
    var formdata = new FormData($("#upload").get());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        beforeSend: function(){
            console.log(formdata);
        },
        success: function(data){
            var pop = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
            pop.document.write(data);
        },
        error:  function(){
            $overlay2.hide();
            alert("Upload Misslyckades B(");
        },
        // Form data
        data: formdata,
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    })
});


function close_nybild(){
    $overlay.hide();
    $nybild.hide();
    reset($nybild);
}

var reset = function(e){
    e.wrap("<form>").closest('form').get(0).reset();
    e.unwrap();
    $preview.html("");

}
});
```

The majority of the code is shamelessly copied from here:
[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: Where is your script to handle the upload? You are missing the url property of your ajax config, you have to put your (php) script path in this property and the script has to be set up to handle the upload. Also make sure your html document is html5 or this method won't work. Check the example you cited again.

Comment: In the example you cited the guy who open the question wrote: `I am using the <a href="http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples">jQuery Form Plugin</a> to upload files.`. Did you tried that? I've and is awesome.

Comment: @dataskills: I dont hava  script to handle the upload just jet, Since i'm leaving out the url it should post to the currently open page, so my expected responce would be the entire output of the php file.

Comment: @Kstro21, I didnt try it jet, but thanks for the recommendation, ill take an other look at it